# JSON Javascript special character How to get value out?

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
    "CASE#":"HW248015",
    "DATE  OF OCCURRENCE":"4/25/2013 22:15",
    "BLOCK":"001XX E CULLERTON ST",
    "IUCR":1090,
    "PRIMARY DESCRIPTION":"ARSON",
    "SECONDARY DESCRIPTION":"ATTEMPT ARSON",
    "LOCATION DESCRIPTION":"VEHICLE NON-COMMERCIAL",
    "ARREST":"Y",
    "DOMESTIC":"N",
    "BEAT":132,
    "WARD":2,
    "FBI CD":9,
    "X COORDINATE":1177803,
    "Y COORDINATE":1890777,
    "LATITUDE":41.85561513,
    "LONGITUDE":-87.62285706,
    "LOCATION":"(41.85561512980008, -87.62285706418919)"
  },
  {
    "CASE#":"HW248271",
    "DATE  OF OCCURRENCE":"4/26/2013 7:45",
    "BLOCK":"044XX W DICKENS AVE",
    "IUCR":1020,
    "PRIMARY DESCRIPTION":"ARSON",
    "SECONDARY DESCRIPTION":"BY FIRE",
    "LOCATION DESCRIPTION":"VEHICLE NON-COMMERCIAL",
    "ARREST":"N",
    "DOMESTIC":"N",
    "BEAT":2522,
    "WARD":31,
    "FBI CD":9,
    "X COORDINATE":1146081,
    "Y COORDINATE":1913539,
    "LATITUDE":41.91873792,
    "LONGITUDE":-87.73871364,
    "LOCATION":"(41.91873791947538, -87.73871364344983)"
  },
```

Here is Json that I have. I want to get value from CASE# but I have no idea to how call that.
I tried

```
db.data[i].CASE#
```

didn't work

```
db.data[i]['CASE#']
```

also didn't work

Anyone have an idea how to call this in Javascript?

Comment: How do you parse your JSON string into your `db.data` object? Can you show the code?

Comment: Given a suitable value for `i`, `db.data[i]['CASE#']` should work fine.

Comment: Thank you guys!. It was a typo on my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try out this `[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9WX8N/)`